# What is the nature of the `data` field in the "Labelled Faces in the Wild" dataset (scikit learn)?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to train a simple HOG face detector using the data fetched from `sklearn.datasets.fetch_lfw_people`.  After fetching the dataset, I find the following keys:

```
In [1]:  lfw_people.keys()
Out[1]:  ['images', 'data', 'target_names', 'DESCR', 'target']
```

- `images` contains the cropped faces
- `target_names` contains the human-readable names
- `target` contains a numerical ID number for the person in a image
- `DESCR` identifies the record as belonging to the LFW dataset.

... but what on **earth** is `data`?

In my case it's a `(13233 x 1850)` numpy array of floats, which is to say one row of 1850 floats per image.

**What is the nature of this `data` field?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(lfw_people.images[0].ravel() == lfw_people.data[0]).all()` evaluates to `True`, so it would appear that the `data` field is simply the image flattened into a vector.

Mystery solved, but this kind of thing really should be indicated upfront :/

Comment: I believe it is documented [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.fetch_lfw_people.html).